# CP/M get running program name

Tags: c, cpm

For a hobby project I'm porting the Standard C Library to the Digital Research CP/M.
Inside CRT0.S (this is the code that runs before your `main()` C function is called) I have no trouble parsing the tail of the command line arguments from the lower memory, but I'm unable to get the running program name i.e. if I type

`memdump 0xfc00 100`

I'd like to obtain memdump or memdump.com from CP/M in a nice way so that I can set my args to (pseudo code) correctly

```
argv[0] = "memdump.com";
argv[1] = "0xfc00";
argv[2] = "100";
```

Comment: Maybe argv[0] is not available once the .com has been loaded? (does CP/M have the Program Segment Prefix?)

Comment: Digging around in the cold storage area of my memory, I came up with `CS:0080h` as the location of the command line buffer in .COM programs. Hopefully the information isn't damaged by frost bite ;)

Comment: Time to dig up the pink-shirt-book... (IIRC QDOS borrowed this part from CP/M)

Comment: The 0080h address (my target is Z80, CP/M 3 Plus) contains only arguments tail. So it starts with argv[1], but there is no program name there. So it would have to be either some weird BDOS/CCP hack, to obtain FCB, or command line. I tried with the 48 function (SCB block), but even there the console buffer is empty.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError lol.  I had no idea that jurassic CP/M was in use anywhere.

Comment: I checked a lot of code samples. For example this example (it is 8080, not Z80, but ok for the research) suffers the same problem. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Command-line_arguments#8080_Assembly 
It just get the args, no command name.

Comment: In DOS, at CS=DS:0x80, there is only the command-tail, prefixed by its length. To obtain the executable file name you may have to peek deeper...

Comment: The HI-TECH Z80 C compiler for CP/M suffers from the same problem. argv[0] is an empty string. The C standard says that argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment, so that aspect of the HI-TECH C compiler is compliant.

Comment: I checked HI-TECH and this is the code they use to get the args : 
args = _getargs((char *)0x81, "myprog"); 
So they pass the program name. I guess I could add this to crt0.s as part of the compilation process as I found no other solution. 

But of course; I wrote a small memory scanner and there is a program name in memory, when you start it. Just don't know how to get to it. :)

Comment: You could set it to a default in `main(argc, argv)`, something like: `static char myarg0 = "myprogname";` `if (argc && !argv[0][0])` `argv[0] = myarg0;`.